# Split series of tuples in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with the index that consists of two parts: id and datetime of the form: *(2345, Timestamp('2009-10-21 17:00:00'))*. This index was created by using the following command:

```
df=df.set_index(df['int'],append=True)
```

After some loop, I would like to split the index back into two separate columns: *id* (2345) and *datetime* (2009-10-21 17:00:00). I know that I can do this by *reset_index()* and then applying some functions relevant for string cells, like:

```
 df=df.reset_index()
 df['index'] = df['index'].astype('str') 
 df[['id','datetime']] = df['index'].str.split(',',expand=True)
 df['id'] = df['id'].str[1:].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

...etc.

Is there an easier way to split the index into *id* and *datetime*?

Answer (score 1):

One efficient method is to extract the NumPy array representation of your tuple series, convert to a list of lists and feed into the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. You can then join onto your original dataframe.

With this method, data types are preserved. Here's a demo:

```
# set up dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[(2345, pd.Timestamp('2009-10-21 17:00:00')), 3],
                   [(2346, pd.Timestamp('2009-10-21 17:00:00')), 6]])
df = df.set_index(0)

# elevate of tuples to series
df = df.reset_index()

# split to list of lists, convert to dataframe and join
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist(), columns=['num', 'date']))\
       .drop(0, axis=1)

print(df)

   1   num                date
0  3  2345 2009-10-21 17:00:00
1  6  2346 2009-10-21 17:00:00
```